# Can't "Attach to Process" to debug using Nsight in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, cuda, nvidia, nsight

I'm trying to debug a cuda application using Nsight with Visual Studio 2008, so I opened the Attach to Process dialog. I set the Transport to be Nsight GPU Debugger. I set the Qualifier to the name of my machine (MONAD in this case). I see a list of processes in the Available Processes widget, but they are all greyed out, and if I click on my application, it remains greyed out and I cannot click the attach button.

[image: Screenshot of the Attach to Process dialog]

When I built the application I made sure to use the -G0 flag when compiling my .cu files with nvcc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please make sure you have set the monitor settings and the environment variables as described in the Nsight Visual Studio Edition 3.0 chapter [Attach Debugging to a Running CUDA Process](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/NsightVisualStudio/3.0/Documentation/UserGuide/HTML/Content/Attach_CUDA_to_Process.htm)

Let me know if that helps.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks - the problem was that I didn't set the NSIGHT_CUDA_DEBUGGER environment variable