# Using Nsight to debug CUDA codes in non-startup project which exports DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cuda, nvidia, nsight

Is there any chance I can debug a *Non-startup* project which outputs DLL file inside a solution? I am using CUDA 5.0, GeForce GTX 670, VS2010, Nsight 3.0.013150, local host.

Currently, I got Disconnect message right after clicking "Start CUDA Debugging"

Btw, CUDA codes are imported to this project from another DLL file.

Please help!! Thanks!!!!!

Comment: You could try to [attach to a running CUDA process](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/NsightVisualStudio/3.0/Documentation/UserGuide/HTML/Content/Attach_CUDA_to_Process.htm)

Comment: @RobertCrovella thanks for your advice. I followed the instruction, unfortunately, it doesn't work, my desire process is grey, and CUDA does not shown up in the Type column as well. Any idea?

Comment: Perhaps you have not set some debug environment variables correctly as indicated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984986/cant-attach-to-process-to-debug-using-nsight-in-visual-studio-2008)

Comment: @RobertCrovella, thanks, I have set the environment variable as 1, it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the "Launch External program" to the EXE that loads the DLL.  This can be done from the Nsight User Properties.  Take a look at [Launching the CUDA Debugger](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/NsightVisualStudio/3.0/Documentation/UserGuide/HTML/Content/Launch_CUDA_Debugger.htm) chapter

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Here is my issue: My solution (.sln) has two projects, project A is the start-up project (.exe), Project B is a project exports dll and then called by A, my CUDA codes are in another DLL, which is called by project B. It seems like the "launch external program" only accept EXE, that mean I cannot launch it to project B? Which is also a DLL, right?